# Sound settings gui not working

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have a problem, im using 12.10 Ubuntu. Recent i sound settings gui working. 
Now it not working. How to get master gui working? My sound working but audio (master) slise in mute permanently also audio settings are empty. However in flash, spotify etc slides working. Also MUTE button is removed.

My alsamixer working.

My hwinfo is this.

```
 hwinfo --sound
24: PCI 709.0: 0401 Multimedia audio controller                 
  [Created at pci.318]
  UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/pci_13f6_111
  Unique ID: GKX6.fT7WCdwsUsC
  Parent ID: 6NW+.FukESQtKoV4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:07:09.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:07:09.0
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "TERRATEC Aureon 5.1"
  Vendor: pci 0x13f6 "C-Media Electronics Inc"
  Device: pci 0x0111 "CM8738"
  SubVendor: pci 0x153b "TERRATEC Electronic GmbH"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1144 "Aureon 5.1"
  Revision: 0x10
  Driver: "snd_cmipci"
  Driver Modules: "snd_cmipci"
  I/O Ports: 0x1000-0x1fff (rw)
  IRQ: 21 (336 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000013F6d00000111sv0000153Bsd00001144bc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_cmipci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_cmipci"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #20 (PCI bridge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resetting User Configuration

For some reason, pulseaudio's user configuration files can become corrupt(unsynced?) in some way, and deleting them (and forcing fresh ones to be generated) fixes a no sound condition. After using the command below, log out/in.

**Ubuntu 12.10/Quantal** (and earlier)

```
rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to command line interface for your sounds settings, if GUI doesn't work for you..

- Install gnome-alsamixer (open terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then execute following command):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
  ```
- Run gnome-alsamixer:

  ```
  alsamixer
  ```

  on the same terminal **AlsaMixer** will be opened.
- Use <kbd>**->**</kbd> or <kbd>**<-**</kbd> arrow keys to change the options. <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys to increase/decrease volumes. <kbd>M</kbd> key to *Mute*. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit.

Hope this short description helps you any how. Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yesterday gui working. But today crashed. And reboot not working. Where is config files?

Comment: Is `alsamixer` working from terminal? What are the scenario you are getting?

Comment: yes is working. my pulseaudio settings are corrupted. it is fixed now.

Comment: Then edit my answer and list the changes you did to fix your problem, then mark this question as solved. It would help others to solve such problems.. :)

Comment: how to mark question solved?

Comment: The `Tick` icon is the notification that you accepted the answer and it works for you.